# Finding general soon for Euler equation given a trial function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Use $y=x^r$ as a trial function to find the general solution to the Euler equation:

$2x^2y''+3xy'-y=0$   ; $x>0$

I have no idea how to start this, as I am only able to work with second order linear DE's.
Thanks for any tips!

Comment: after we find the values of r, how do we get the general solution?

Comment: ah, can anyone confirm if this is right?

$y=c_1x^{-1}+c_2x^{0.5}$

Comment: great thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Is 'Using as a trial function' just substituting the function in the equation? If it is the case, then

$$2r(r-1)x^r+3rx^r-x^r=0$$
or
$$(2r^2+r-1)x^r=0$$
that is, $r=1/2$ or $r=-1$.

Comment: Now that we have values for r, what would the form of the general solution be?